# my activity not being called with action_view

Tags: android

i have create an activity in an application com.example.one which calls another activity in application com.example.two.
In the activity two manifest i have declared the following intent-filter

```
  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
```

However on calling this activity with action - Intent.ACTION_VIEW or even with android.intent.action.VIEW directly invokes the browser rather than a Intent chooser that i have put.

```
Intent ii=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        ii.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(ii,"done"));
```

kindly update why i am not getting the intent chooser for browser and my activity.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to include another browsable category with intent filter.
`<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />`

Answer (score 0):

Clear the browser defaults settings, than try to invoke your
method, it should ask for the action to choose the available apps,
with this time only and always, here you go with it.

To clear go to the settings -> Apps -> browsers [Chrome, Firefox or any other if installed]
than to each browser press button 'Clear defaults'.

Comment: Okay, try to call this activity like this:- Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("[http://www.google.com](http://www.google.com)"));
startActivity(i);

Comment: I GOT THE SOLUTION.I FIRST RAN THE ACTIVITY TWO AND IT INSTALLED ON THE EMULATOR AND THEN ACTIVITY ONE.